# save the button was click and display the option with date as summary in android app

Tags: android

choose which diaper is chosen and record the date and time, every time a diaper is changed then save it.

[image]

I tried to use shared preference but i do not really know how to use it properly as I am completely new to this.

Comment: I'm developing an application about baby tracker too. I suggested you using database instead of SharedPreference. RealmDB is good.

Comment: You can use SQLite for your purpose.

Comment: SQLite is way to go. It will also help you keep a track of the history of the changes if you need that feature later.  You can find a tutorial here https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Answer (score 1):

Try This
Define an Array list in which you will save your date time

```
SharedPreferences  sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
List<Date> dateList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then on diaper  change function try this

```
public void onDiaperChange(Date date){

if(sharedpreferences.contains("DateList")){
     dateList = sharedpreferences.getString("DateList","");
}
dateList.add(date);

sharedpreferences.putString(ObjectSerializer.serialize(dateList));
```

}

and to get the list use this

```
public void getAllDateTime(){
List<Date> fetchedData = new ArrayList<>();
 fetchedData = (ArrayList<Date>) ObjectSerializer.deserialize(prefs.getString("DateList", ObjectSerializer.serialize(new ArrayList<Date>())));
  } catch (IOException e) {
}
```

you can get ObjectSerializer from here [ObjectSerializer](https://github.com/apache/pig/blob/89c2e8e76c68d0d0abe6a36b4e08ddc56979796f/src/org/apache/pig/impl/util/ObjectSerializer.java)

Answer (score 0):

Use Realm to store data in database

To store data is like

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
realm.beginTransaction();
DateModel datemodel = realm.createObject(DateM.class);
datemodel.setDate(your date);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Get stored data :

```
RealmResults< DateModel > result = realm.where(DateModel.class)
                .findAll();
```